# messageProperties.setCorrelationIdString is not working

Tags: spring, amqp

I have  a scenario that the messaging flow is based on the correlation id. So I am setting the correlation Id String in sender Message Properties. But I am not receiving the same id in receiver message, coming null. I have seen the other option to set the same correlation id in message processor class, can set the Message. in "convert And Send". but please let me know is there any way to get the correlation id in simple send and receive functions.

The `messProperties.setCorrelationId()` is deprecated in latest spring version.

My sender:

```
public class Send {

    private static  ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("rabbitConfiguration.xml");
    private static RabbitTemplate template = context.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MessageProperties messProperties = new MessageProperties();
        messProperties.setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
        //messProperties.setCorrelationId("coid".getBytes());
        messProperties.setCorrelationIdString("dee");
        Message messageToSend = new Message("Message with ssl".getBytes(), messProperties);
        template.send("message.ssl", messageToSend);

    }

}
```

MyReceiver Code:

```
public class Receive {
    private static  ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("rabbitConfiguration.xml");
    private static RabbitTemplate template = context.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Message recMess = template.receive("SSLQueue");
            String id=new String(recMess.getMessageProperties().getCorrelationId());
            System.out.println("the corelation id from receiver is"+id);
            String recStr = new String(recMess.getBody());
            System.out.println("received message is"+recStr);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

CorrelationId and CorrelationIdString is inconsistent:

In MessageProperties the setCorrelationId(byte[] correlationId) is deprecated.

BUT the DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter still uses a (deprecated) CorrelationIdPolicy of type BYTES.

So, if you look at DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter.toMessageProperties

`if (!CorrelationIdPolicy.BYTES.equals(this.correlationIdPolicy) && correlationId != null) {
   target.setCorrelationIdString(correlationId);
}`

the correlationId is not set...

I think that before 2.0, the only way to fix this is to configure your RabbitTemplate in this way:

```
DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter messageConverter = new DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter();
messageConverter.setCorrelationIdAsString(DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter.CorrelationIdPolicy.STRING);

RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
template.setMessagePropertiesConverter(messageConverter);
```